# getroute with waypoints error using gmap3 jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, dictionary

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#test").gmap3({ 
  getroute:{
    options:{
        origin:"Trenggalek, Indonesia",
         waypoints: [{location: "Blitar, Indonesia", stopover: false},{location: "Malang, Indonesia", stopover: false}],
        destination:"Surabaya, Indonesia",
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    },
    callback: function(results){
      if (!results) return;
      $(this).gmap3({
        map:{
          options:{
            zoom: 13,  
            center: [-33.879, 151.235]
          }
        },
        directionsrenderer:{
          options:{
            directions:results
          } 
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

But when I change location with lattitude and longitude then error happened

```
waypoints: [{location: "Blitar, Indonesia", stopover: false},{location: [-7.988518,112.619262], stopover: false}],
```

How to change location using lattitude and longitude ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if location is coordinates, it needs to be a google.maps.LatLng object, not an array of numbers. Please read the documentation.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsWaypoint

change:

```
waypoints: [{location: "Blitar, Indonesia", stopover: false},{location: [-7.988518,112.619262], stopover: false}],
```

to:

```
waypoints: [{location: "Blitar, Indonesia", stopover: false},{location: new google.maps.LatLng(-7.988518,112.619262), stopover: false}],
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X7mx2/)